# Bind class item in the loop

Tags: vue.js

i want to bind my button only on the element that i added to the cart, it's working well when i'm not in a loop but in a loop anything happen. i'm not sure if it was the right way to add the index like that in order to bind only the item clicked, if i don't put the index every button on the loop are binded and that's not what i want in my case.

```
:loading="isLoading[index]"
```

here the vue :

```
<div class="container column is-9">
               <div class="section">
                   <div class="columns is-multiline">
                       <div class="column is-3" v-for="(product, index) in computedProducts">
                           <div class="card">
                               <div class="card-image">
                                   <figure class="image is-4by3">
                                       <img src="" alt="Placeholder image">
                                   </figure>
                               </div>
                               <div class="card-content">
                                   <div class="content">
                                       <div class="media-content">
                                           <p class="title is-4">{{product.name}}</p>
                                           <p class="subtitle is-6">Description</p>
                                           <p>{{product.price}}</p>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>

                                   <div class="content">
                                       <b-button class="is-primary" @click="addToCart(product)" :loading="isLoading[index]"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Ajouter au panier</b-button>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
```

here the data :

```
 data () {
                return {
                    products : [],
                    isLoading: false,
                }
            },
```

here my add to cart method where i change the state of isLoading :

```
addToCart(product) {
                this.isLoading = true
                axios.post('cart/add-to-cart/', {
                    data: product,
                }).then(r => {
                    this.isLoading = false

                }).catch(e => {
                    this.isLoading = false
                 });


            }
```

Comment: each button has its loading state ? do you want to apply some style if it's loading ?

Comment: when i click to the button of the item i want to bind loading class only to the clicked element

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `isLoading` to an array of booleans, and your `addToCart` method to also have an `index` argument.

Data:

```js
return {
  // ...
  isLoading: []
}
```

Methods:

```js
addToCart(product, index) {
  // ...
}
```

And on your button, also include `index`:

```js
@click="addToCart(product, index)"
```

By changing `isLoading` to an empty array, I don't think `isLoading[index] = true` will be reactive since `index` on `isLoading` doesn't exist yet. So you would use `Vue.set` in your `addToCart(product, index)` such as:

```js
this.$set(this.isLoading, index, true)
```

This will ensure that changes being made to `isLoading` will be reactive.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: many thanks for your reply, i will try that when i go back to the desk and i let you know :)))

Comment: i get this error when i do it like this :  [Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: false
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in false"

Comment: I'm guessing your `isLoading` data is still set to `isLoading: false` rather than an array like so: `isLoading: []`. Have you changed it?

Answer (score 0):

add on data `productsLoading: []`

on add to cart click, add loop index to productsLoading.
`this.productsLoading.push(index)`

after http request done, remove index from productsLoading.
`this.productsLoading.splice(this.productoading.indexOf(index), 1)`

and check button with `:loading=productsLoading.includes(index)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create another component only for product card,
for better option as show below 
Kindly follow this steps.
place the content of card in another vue component as shown below.

```
<!-- Product.vue  -->
<template>
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-image">
       <figure class="image is-4by3">
           <img src="" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content">
          <div class="media-content">
              <p class="title is-4">{{product.name}}</p>
              <p class="subtitle is-6">Description</p>
              <p>{{product.price}}</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
         <b-button class="is-primary" @click="addToCart(product)" :loading="isLoading"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Ajouter au panier</b-button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</templete>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "Product",
    data() {
      return {
        isLoading: false
      }
    },
    props: {
      product: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
     addToCart(product) {
        this.isLoading = true
        axios.post('cart/add-to-cart/', {
           data: product,
        }).then(r => {
          this.isLoading = false
        }).catch(e => {
         this.isLoading = false
        });
    }
   }
 }
</script>
```

Change your component content as shown below.

```
<template>
<div class="container column is-9">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="columns is-multiline">
            <div class="column is-3" v-for="(product, index) in computedProducts">
               <product :product="product" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</templete>
<script>

  import Product from 'path to above component' 

  export default {
   components: {
     Product 
   }
 }
</script>
```

so in the above method you can reuse the component in other components as well.
Happy coding :-)

Comment: many thanks for your reply, i will also try this solution :) i let you know when i tested !! many thanks